# removing subchapter numbers when using exheader

Tags: chapters

I am writing an article which includes exercises but I don't want them to be part of the chapter sub-count. I don't want to put the full code up as its long, but is there a way to remove the following code from the chapter section.

```
\exheader
Write the following numbers in figures
\begin{exercisescol}[noitemsep]{2}
\question[5103]{Five thousand, one hundred and three}
\question[370091]{Three hundred thousand, seven hundred and ninety one}
\question[2500000]{Two and a half million}
\question[1702204]{One million, seven hundred and two thousand, two hundred and four}
\end{exercisescol}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `\section{Exercises}%` from  `\newcommand{\exheader}{...` (or please provide  an example of the expected output)

Comment: Thanks this has worked.